# null initialstate in redux reducer is giving me an error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a photoReducer set up to receive data from the backend. However, I set it's initialstate to null (I also set it to an empty array which gave me the same error).

My question is how can I set it to an initial value which would not be null or return an error.

When a new user signs up they will obviously have no data.

Here is my code for the reducer.

```
export default function PhotosReducer(state = null, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "SetPhotos":
            return {...state, photos: action.payload}
    default:
        return state 
}}
```

```
 return (
        <div className="photos">
            {photos.map(photo => {
                return <div key={photo.id}><img src={photo.photourl} loading="lazy" alt="pic" key={photo.id} onClick={() => clickedPhoto(photo)}/>
                </div>
            })}
            {message && <div className="message">{message}</div>}
        </div>
        )
}
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'photos' of null
```

Comment: Its a common and good practice to use `null` when there is no data . what is the error ? Also add the code which gives you the error .

Comment: Ill edit the question with the error.

Comment: Add the code which throws you the error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before mapping you can check if it exists and is not empty**

this way map is only called if there are some items in an array

```js
 return (
        <div className="photos">
            {photos && photos.length>0 && photos.map(photo => {
                return <div key={photo.id}><img src={photo.photourl} loading="lazy" alt="pic" key={photo.id} onClick={() => clickedPhoto(photo)}/>
                </div>
            })}
            {message && <div className="message">{message}</div>}
        </div>
        )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change initialstate to empty object:

```
PhotosReducer(state = {}, action)
```